# Apache mod_rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, apache2, url-encoding

I have a problem with the mod_rewrite module for Apache 2.2
My code will neither work on localhost (Wamp on Win8 Pro, IPv6) nor on the webhotel (site5.com).
My goal is to generate SEO friendly URLs as:

> www.xy.com/featured-artists.html

instead of:

> www.xy.com/index.php?pageID=Artists

The PHP variable $pageID is defined on line 1 in my index.php:

```
<?php isset($_GET['pageID']) ? $pageID = $_GET['pageID'] : $pageID = 'Forside';?>
```

The code for the rewrite in my .htaccess file looks as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately that doesn't have any effect on the site. The .htaccess file is working properly though, since other sections like

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?pageID=404
```

work as expected.
No matter what I do - it won't work. So I really hope that some of you can help me with that.

Thanks!

Comment: @downvoter : This is a genuine question, well-formatted and includes all details. Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

Mod_rewrite doesn't seem to be turned on. Your rules are inclosed in a `IfModule` container:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1
</IfModule>
```

So the rules aren't going to get executed. You need to turn on mod rewrite in server config (or your webhost) if you want any of your rules to work. Otherwise, it doesn't matter what you try.

Once you had mod_rewrite loaded, your rules should do close to what you want. It'll take `/something` and internally rewrite it to `/index.php?page=somethin`.